# From Drive to Blobstore using Picker

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, blobstore, google-picker

I have the Google picker set up, as well as Blobstore. I'm able to upload files from my local machine to the Blobstore, but now I have the Picker set up, it works, but I don't know know how to use the info (url? fileid?) to then load that selected file into the Blobstore? Any tips on how to do this? I haven't been able to find much of anything on it on Googles resources

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct link between the Google Picker and the App Engine Blobstore. They are kind of different tools for different jobs. The Google Picker is designed as an end user tool, to select data from a users Google account. It just so happens that the Picker also provides an upload interface (to Google Drive) as well. The Blobstore on the other hand, is designed as a blob storage mechanism for your App Engine application.

In theory, you could write a script to connect the two, but there are a few considerations:

- Your app would need access to the users Google Drive account using OAuth2. This is necessary, as the Picker API is a client side API, whereas the Blobstore API is a server side API. You would need to send the selected document URL to the server, then download the document and finally save it to Blobstore.
- Unless you then deleted the data from Drive (very risky due to point 3), your data would be persisted in 2 places
- You cannot know for sure if the user selected an existing file, or uploaded a new one
- Not a great user experience - the user things they are uploading to Drive

In essence, this sounds like a bad idea! What is your use case?

Answer (score 0):

@Gwyn - I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to your solution, but I had an idea about problem #3: You cannot know for sure if the user selected an existing file, or uploaded a new one

Would it be possible to use [`Response.VIEW`](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#Response) to see what view they were using when the file was selected? If you have one view constructor for Drive files and one for Upload files, something like

```
var driveView = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
var uploadView = new google.picker.DocsUploadView();
```

would that allow you to know whether the file was a new upload (safe to delete) or an existing file (leave it alone)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to pick a file from your own Google Drive and move it to the Blobstore.

1)First you have to perform **Oauth** for Google Drive API

2)Using the picker when you select a file from drive, you need to get it's **id**

3)Using the **id** obtained in step 2 you can programmatically download it using Drive API

4)After downloading the file you can use FileService(deprecated though) to upload the file to the
Blobstore.